# No more data to read from socket - for long query with multiple IN clause

Tags: oracle19c

I have a very long query

```
select commonreso0_.ID_PK as col_0_0_, commonreso0_.DISPLAY_PATH as col_1_0_, commonreso0_.OBJECT_TYPE as col_2_0_, commonreso0_.SD_NAME as col_3_0_ 
from nms_perf_linux.state_common_resource commonreso0_ where commonreso0_.SD_NAME in 
(e1 ,'e2', e3, .....e990)  or commonreso0_.SD_NAME in (e1,e2,....e900) or commonreso0_.SD_NAME in (e1,e2,....e900).....10x.....or commonreso0_.SD_NAME in (e1,e2,....e900)
```

When I run this query from SQL developer, I am getting **"No more data to read from socket"**

I am using oracle19c, with ojdbc11.
On tnsNames.ora I have: SERVER = SHARED
Also, I tried with oprim_peek_user_binds as TRUE and also as FALSE.
If I am running this query on oracle12c, everything is working fine

Comment: Such a query is essence of pure evil. Oracle has to allocate a lot of memory in shared memory region in order to parse. This can lead to contention, outages and possibly to other failures. Check databases alert.log(with your DBA), possibly this query triggers some DB internal error. There were various articles written about this topic, search for "Oracle dynamic where clause". There is a reason why IN clause has limit to 1000 element, from db point of view it would be better to store all those fields in temp table, but I'm not sure whether your framework supports it.

Comment: Nothing on logs. I discovered the same error in oracle 12c also, but it seems that it supports more IN clauses than oracle19c. This makes me think that is some parameter to be set. May be linked by "query size"?